# Wine and windows virus

Tags: malware, wine

Does installing wine pose a risk of virus infection?
I'm afraid a powerful virus can bypass wine sandbox and gain access to root linux.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute native executables inside wine, so if the virus knows what to do with a native executable, and if you have write access to the executable, then it is possible.

Wine is not a sandbox, it is a compatibility layer. There is nothing preventing code from crossing back and forth other than a lack of programmers with the knowledge and desire.

Comment: +1 for 'Wine is not a sandbox', it _does_ make a POSIX system compatible with win32 apps, including viruses

Comment: Check this out: `http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=72598`.     This guy installed some viruses and then posted what happened. That was way back in 2005, when Wine was nowhere near as good at running applications as it is today. I would suggest you assume Linux / UNIX with WINE is no more secure against viruses than Windows.

Comment: “Wine is not a sandbox” is spot on.